# $\limsup$ and sequence divergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I don't know how to solve the following question, your help is very much appreciated:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence where $1\le (a_n) \le 2$ for all $n$.
>
> Prove or disprove: if $(a_n)$ is divergent, $$\overline{ \lim_{n \to \infty}} a_n * \overline{ \lim_{n \to \infty}}\left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right)>1$$
>
> Where $$\overline{ \lim_{n \to \infty}}$$
>
> Means $\limsup$.

Comment: Hint: $\limsup 1/a_n=1/\liminf a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

As $(a_n)$ is divergent, $2 \ge \alpha := \lim \sup a_n > \lim \inf a_n =: \beta \ge 1$ $\implies \exists \ \gamma\in (1, \alpha)$, such that $\beta < \gamma < \alpha$.

On the other hand:

$$\lim \sup \frac1{a_n} = \frac1{\lim \inf a_n} > \frac1{\gamma}$$

Therefore:

$$\lim \sup a_n \times \lim \sup \frac1{a_n} > \gamma \times \frac1{\gamma} = 1$$